# Meaning of "go for with"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I ran into an unfamiliar phrase in this [article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-56660294).

> And that's exactly what the Indonesian government is **going for with** Mandalika, a new tourist area touted as the next Bali.

I looked up this phrase, but I couldn't find it in dictionary.
Could someone  please tell me its meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **go for** is a phrasal verb that can be used to mean 'seek to achieve, try to have', etc.

The sentence means: That's exactly what the Indonesian government is **trying to do** with (or in regard to) Mandalika, [...]

> Go for (something)
> phrasal verb with go verb
> (TRY)
>
> to try to have or achieve something:
>
> *She tripped me as I **went for** the ball.
>
> The Russian relay team will again be **going for** the
> gold medal at the Olympic Games.*

[Go for (something) (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-for-sth)

Comment: Thank you so much. In this case, does "with" following "go for" mean " in regard to" ?

Comment: @Learner-Koara - I have edited my answer.